# JWPlayer quality button disappear with WOWZA MPEG DASH videos

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, jwplayer, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I install and configured the Wowza server and it is working fine as following screenshot:

[image]

After that I copied the MPEG DASH URL and I tested on jwplayer (they have a page to test MPEG DASH videos: http://www.jwplayer.com/innovation/roadmap/mpeg-dash) as following and it is working:

[image]

The JWPlayer has a quality selector button by default, but when I used the wawza default video sample, the quality button disappears!

Comment: Where are you running this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you don't see the quality selector button in JWPlayer is because there are no alternate renditions of your video.

The Wowza Transcoder add-on works with **Live** streams and your link is a **VOD** (video on demand).

There are two ways to make this work:

1. Create the frame-aligned renditions of your video file manually and [use SMIL files to provide an adaptive bitrate stream](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?546#abr_vod).
2. Create a Wowza module and use the `Stream` class [to publish a live stream using your static video file as input](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?162-How-to-do-basic-server-side-publishing-with-Stream-class-streams). Then pass this live stream to the transcoder add-on to automatically create the adaptive bitrate stream.

Good luck!

Update:

If you don't have the time to do this for your demo you can use the files hosted on the Wowza website:

- [bigbuckbunny_450.mp4](http://www.wowza.com/downloads/images/bigbuckbunny_450.mp4) (450kbps total bitrate)
- [bigbuckbunny_750.mp4](http://www.wowza.com/downloads/images/bigbuckbunny_750.mp4) (750kbps total bitrate)
- [bigbuckbunny_1100.mp4](http://www.wowza.com/downloads/images/bigbuckbunny_1100.mp4) (1100kbps total bitrate)
- [bigbuckbunny_1500.mp4](http://www.wowza.com/downloads/images/bigbuckbunny_1500.mp4) (1500kbps total bitrate)

Comment: what is the recommendation? option 1 or 2

Comment: If you want to do VOD then do 1. because you'll encode the files only once. Transcoding using 2. means your server will be used to live transcode each time someone watches the live stream and it's a waste of resources.

Comment: There's a guide on using `ffmpeg` to create the renditions: http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?192-Encoding-Suggestions-for-Video-on-Demand. Do yourself a favor and use `libfdk_aac` instead of `aac` however.