# video quality button not showing on jw player

Tags: android, video-streaming, jwplayer

I'm using JWPlayer in my android app to play my m3u8 video streams.

```
JWPlayerView playerView = findViewById(R.id.jwplayer);
new KeepScreenOnHandler(playerView, getWindow());
PlaylistItem video = new PlaylistItem.Builder()
                    .file(media.getUrl())
                    .title(media.Caption)
                    .description(media.Description)
                    .image(media.postThumbnail)
                    .build();
playerView.addOnFullscreenListener(this);
            playerView.load(video);
```

But the quality selector button doesn't always appear, although I've checked the the content of the [m3u8](http://5flix.cdn.octivid.com/vod/_definst_/smil:2017-09-25/vidCEsFi1PJtu.smil/playlist.m3u8), it contains about 3 types of streams: 1080, 480 and 240.

**I tried to manually handle them, but the weird part is that the playerView.getQualityLevels() array has only one element, and the playerView.getVisualQuality() is always null!**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31956759/jwplayer-quality-button-disappear-with-wowza-mpeg-dash-videos

Answer (score 0):

For HSL, it is automatic, to get the bitrate or the quality, you can do it as follows:

```
player.addOnVisualQualityListener(new VideoPlayerEvents.OnVisualQualityListener() {

    @Override
        public void onVisualQuality(VisualQuality visualQuality) {
            if(visualQuality.getQualityLevel().getBitrate() < 0){
                // error
            }

            else {
                bitrate = visualQuality.getQualityLevel().getBitrate();                    
            }
        }
    });
```